# Text object - CurrentDate-1

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to have a text field say: Shipments Picking Up (CurrentDate-1)

How would I get this to display properly? So it would show: Shipments Picking Up May 31

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will work

```
"Shipments Picking Up " & totext(currentdate,"MMM d")
```